# How to handle performance of flutter app with video_player

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make an app like Instagram in Flutter. I have a profile page, video page, comment bottom sheet and etc. When a user is on a video page, in comments clicks on a profile, and then clicks on that user's post, another instance of a video page with new data is created. In short, I have some video pages in my route stack. Each video page contains [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) to show videos from the network. Is not affect performance that I have some instances of video page? I don't want to dispose of video players because users can return to the previous page. How does Instagram do that? On Instagram, you can open many video pages with back ability without lag or reduced performance. Can you give me some tips about this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new video player widget requires a video controller, initiliazing this video controller in flutter is very expensive and if you create many of them, lets say 10 video controllers you may run into memory overflow, i would recommend creating lets say 5 video controllers at the beggining of your app start up, and keep them in a pool of video controllers, there you can dynamically change the video data source on one of not used video controllers, or if all of them are in use, use the first that was created and so on